# how to find the routers address in an open wifi network

Tags: wireless, default, gateway

For example if i connect to a wifi network and i want to know the address of router ie: the default gateway, how to do i find it in linux.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
route -n | grep 'UG[ \t]' | awk '{print $2}'
or
cat /etc/network/interfaces | grep gateway
```

Answer (score 0):

"If I connect to a wifi network" - by doing this you have, in all probability, issued a `DHCP` request (broadcast to all nodes on your LAN). The `DHCP` response told your system what its IP Address/Netmask was, what its dafault gateway was, and many other things.

You can see other nodes on your network (if they've sent a packet) via:

```
arp -an
```

You can see your default route (where almost ALL the packets get sent) with:

```
ip route
```

If you have done `sudo apt-get install tracepath`, you can see all the systems between your system and `slashdot.org` with:

```
tracepath slashdot.org
```

Comment: but when  run the arp command on my linux machine it shows me various but not my windows machine(the one on which i am running vmware and linux).How do I know the ip address of my windows machine through linux()vmware

Answer (score 0):

You can find the IP router through :

```
netstat -r -n
```

or

```
route -n
```

or

```
ip route show default
ip route | grep default
```